# ignoring parts of string using sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I have a string of the form

```
"http://something.another.thing:13541/random-text.txt"
```

I want to extract the `"something.another.thing:13541"` part out of it, so I am using

```
sscanf(uri, "http://%s/%*s", host);
```

To read the specified part into a buffer `host`. `%*s` should be ignoring the parts of the string after `/` right?

Comment: Does it always start with `http://` or could it also be `https://` or simply with the address?

Comment: It would always start with `http://`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not discarding parts, you need a delimiter `[^?]`

Try

```
char *uri = "http://something.another.thing:13541/random-text.txt";
char host[266];

sscanf(uri, "http://%265[^/]", host); // %265 prevents buffer overflows
printf("%s\n", host);
```

Since a host can not contain more than 255 bytes + say 10 for the port, `char host[266];` is what you want to cover all possible cases.

Another option is to get the maximum size with `getconf HOST_NAME_MAX` and pass it to the program if you are under some linux.

Comment: How does `%99` prevent buffer overflow?

Comment: It means that it will write only up to 99 characters + the 0-terminator to the buffer.

Comment: What if we have more than 99 characters (an unknown number) to write?

Comment: You have an edit, for other cases (an unknow number of elements) you need to use other approaches, there are a lot `cs50 -> GetString`, `readline`, `getline`, a tunned `fgets` using dynamic memory ...